# Using Jquery .get find if data is empty

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using a .get function of jquery to poll data continuously from the server. The problem i am running into is i want to know if data is being passed or if it is empty.
The .get function is running a php document that only echoes data if there is new data from the server, so 90% of the time, there is no new data. But how do i know when there is? The .get function has a parameter called "data", but i have no idea how to check stuff with it or how to convert it to DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting raw data use something like this:

```
$.get("test.php",
   function(data){
     if (data==""){
       alert ("Server responding");
       }
      else{
     alert ("Server is asleep");
      }

   });
```

The best approach is to parse JSON (Which is more flexible to handle) from php to your jquery functionyou can use
isEmptyObject()

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject({}) // true
jQuery.isEmptyObject({ foo: "bar" }) // false
```

Take a look here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/

Comment: well the above with the data == "" doesn't work...so how do i use json

Comment: You have to parse JSON from your php file to the jquery string
I assume that you use echo to pass the data from your php file 
JSON is working with array. You have to use [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) 

Then you can handle the parsed data. Here is some tutorials on how to do it
[link](http://webhole.net/2009/11/28/how-to-read-json-with-javascript/)